# Entity Framework - Get parents based on child collection

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I should retrieve Tickets where, for each, the last Messages has TeamId not null.

With code:

```
var test1 = await _context.Tickets.Include(x => x.Messages)
            .Where(x => x.Messages.OrderByDescending(y => y.InsertDate).First().TeamId != null).ToListAsync();

var test2 = await _context.Tickets.Include(x => x.Messages)
            .Where(x => x.Messages.Last().TeamId != null).ToListAsync();
```

both returns all tickets, even those containing only one element in Messages with TeamId null.

What is the right query to get Tickets where the last element of  does not have the TeamId null?

Comment: Are you 100% sure? The `Where` should be decisive and AFAIK there have never been any bugs in this area. But then, we don't know the EF version and database provider you're using.

Comment: Try removing `.Include(x => x.Messages)`

Comment: That code doesn't appear to be reproducible. It appears to be EF Core code as the `.First()` would not work with EF6, though I tested a similar scenario with a null-able property and the results filtered correctly. Perhaps include the definition for Ticket & Message. The test2 example won't be predictable since `Last` with no order-by clause.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the wait. Yes, I confirm. For testing I tried to restart the migration but the result is the same. I am using the latest version of ef core 6. Here the screenshot with the query obtained from sql profiler https://shorturl.at/dhqB3. As you can see there is a global filter on the IsDeleted column. I see it is not adding the specified filter on the teamid.

Comment: It works correctly with ```var test3 = await _context.Tickets.Where(x => x.Messages.OrderByDescending(y => y.InsertDate).Any(y => y.TeamId != null)).ToListAsync();``` but it doesn't with First. Include(x => x.Messages) it makes no difference

Comment: Please add the classes and mappings, and the SQL query *as text*, not an image (the image is inaccessible, BTW). And please tag the EF version you're using.

Comment: I've got an update. Here is the code https://dotnetfiddle.net/fuobuI and it is working. Also with Ef core 3.1 it is working, but if i test with 6.0 on vs2022 latest version, it doesn't work anymore and test2 has one element. My spec https://pastebin.com/jpXeaskg

Comment: Please don't post these external sources. The question text should contain all source code that's necessary to answer it.

Comment: Yep. More details on https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26744

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EF core 5, then its possible, that filtered include would work, although I don't remember if the `First()` is supported. Give it a try.

Also, I do not have the way to check this code - I'm typing from mobile, so you should validate it.

```cs
var test1 = await _context.Tickets
.Include(x => x.Messages.Where(x => x.Messages.OrderByDescending(y => y.InsertDate).First().TeamId != null))
.Where(x => x.Messages != null)
.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Tested (I moved OrderByDescending before the Where), but results do not change, it returns tickets with TeamId null